# Como organizar Services e Repositories em uma aplicação MVC?

Tags: controller, view, model

Possuo uma aplicação API REST em NodeJs já organizada no em MVC, mas ainda não entendo como utilizar na prática os services e repositories. Por favor, podem me ajudar a separar as camadas?

```
//MODEL
const db = require('../db');
exports.getProducts = function() {
    try {
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM products';
        return db.execute(query);
    } catch(error){
        return error;
    }
};
```

```
//CONTROLLER
const ProductsModel = require('../models/Products');
exports.getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {  
        const result = await ProductsModel.getProducts();
        const response = {
            length: result.length,
            products: result.map(prod => {
                return {
                    productId: prod.productId,
                    name: prod.name,
                    price: prod.price,
                    request: {
                        type: 'GET',
                        description: 'Retorna os detalhes de um produto específico',
                        url: process.env.URL_API + 'products/' + prod.productId
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        return res.status(200).send(response);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).send({ error: error });
    }
};
```

```
//ROUTE
const ProductsController = require('../controllers/product-controller');
router.get('/', ProductsController.getProducts);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que antes de sair alterando todo seu código e a estrutura do seu projeto, é necessário primeiro entender o que você está fazendo, e principalmente, o motivo pelo qual está fazendo.

O padrão MVC divide seu projeto em 3 camadas, porém para aplicações grandes, com muitas regras de negócio e entidades, isso não é o suficiente para mantermos o sistema organizado, sem duplicação de código e alinhado as boas práticas.

Com isso, foram criados vários padrões de projeto para dividir as responsabilidades, tornar o sistema mais independente e testável.

Falando de forma bem resumida, a responsabilidade do **Controller** é de receber uma requisição HTTP, fazer as devidas validações e tratá-la com uma resposta.

Já o **serviço** é a camada onde há regras de negócio do sistema, e podem ser chamadas e utilizadas por diversas parte da aplicação, como um projeto web e uma API, e ambas fazendo a chamada para um mesmo método do serviço.

O **repositório** é a camada responsável pela comunicação e operação com o banco de dados. O domínio, a API, o serviço, e as outras partes do sistema não devem saber se comunicar com o banco, pois a responsabilidade e abstração dessa lógica fica toda no repositório, assim se o banco de dados precisar ser alterado, somente o repositório precisará de adaptações.

Com isso em mente, recomendo que você dê uma pesquisada pelos tópicos do fórum, bem como no google, em explicações mais aprofundadas sobre cada camada e a responsabilidade de cada uma, pois o assunto vai bem longe.

Espero ter ajudado.